# jquery slider not transitioning smooth

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-slider

Thanks to Christiaan Scheermeijer I got the slider to transition correctly. But now it seems the focus of the images is off. Do I need to use z-index or something to get the slides to smooth properly? Currently the only one that "fades" like it should, is slide 4, transitioning back to slide 1. I'm really puzzled. I tried timing on the fades, which doesn't seem to be the problem. It seems like the 'next slide' is just popping into the foreground over the slide it should be fading from.

http://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/haBAS/2/

```
$('#hi1').fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
var slide = 0,
slides = 4,
ids = [
    '#hi1',
    '#hi2',
    '#hi3',
    '#hi4', ];
slideShow = setInterval(function () {
    var nextSlide = slide + 1;
    if (nextSlide > slides - 1) {
        nextSlide = 0;
    }
    $(ids[nextSlide]).fadeTo(100, 1.0);
    $(ids[slide]).fadeTo(1200, 0);
    slide++;
    if (slide > slides - 1) {
        slide = 0;
    }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: What if you change `fadeTo` timer from `100` to `1000`? Or maybe use `1200` on both? Or maybe I just didn't understand your problem correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this.

Change:

```
$(ids[nextSlide]).fadeTo(100, 1.0);
$(ids[slide]).fadeTo(1200, 0);
```

To:

```
$(ids[slide]).fadeTo(300, 0);
$(ids[nextSlide]).fadeTo(2300, 1.0);
```

And add to the `#container` CSS rule:

```
background-color: #000;
```

Also, you might consider this change too (though it's not necessary to get it working - it will simplify your code).

Change:

```
slide++;
if (slide > slides - 1) {
    slide = 0;
}
```

To:

```
slide = nextSlide;
```

(You've already calculated what the next slide will be, you can just use it instead of recalculating and then checking bounds.)

One other suggestion would be to consider using `ids.length` where you have `slides`, and remove the `slides` `var` - reason this might make sense is to that if you decide to add or remove slides in the future, you don't have to remember to also update the `slides` count - it will just work with however many you've specified in the `ids` array.

Consider this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5d294/).

Comment: Thanks, I tried the 1200, and it just shows the other fading in, while it's fading out. it's strange. And thanks for the code tweaks.

Comment: @WASasquatch I made an edit to slow down the transition so it will finish fading out, then fade in the next one.  I also added a black background color so you don't get a "white flash" once it's faded out.  I also forked a new JSFiddle from yours with the changes.